# Simple I/O (reading a text file)

Tags: c#

I looked online for a simple example of file reading and writing. Being a python graduate and moving into C# was a big step for me, but I do really love the language.

I've seen people do file I/O with StringReader, FileSystem, and I hear that Stream is also used. As a beginner to the language, one who doesn't know too many complicated concepts (but has the basic stuff down, methods, classes, functions) how would I go about reading a file correctly? I see people using the "using" keyword, and then treating it like a class or method. I have no clue what thats all about. I'm looking for something like

```
    FileSystem() f = file.read("test.txt")
    f.DoStuff()
```

In python, it was really easy to use a dictionary stored in another file. All I had to do was:

```
    import Dict.py
    # Now i have access to all of Dict's dictionaries. We'll say the name of one
    # of the dictioanries is "f".

    print Dict.f[1] # Or whatever. Now i can use the dictionary f like it was local.
```

My goal is to make a hangman game. I'm trying to pick a random word from a list of words (English dictionary) and have them guess that word, but I don't know how to do such things like read the file, and import its contents. Again, as simple as you can make it so a beginner can understand would be really helpful. Thanks a million!

Comment: I suggest you look at the `File` class - it has all kinds of helpful methods, such as `File.ReadAllLines`, which means you don't need to worry about closing the stream afterwards...

Comment: Documentation is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404278(v=vs.110).aspx  MSDN is your best friend for finding how to do things in .NET.  The documentation is extensive.

Comment: or `StreamReader` or `FileStream` if you want to read it yourself. Applying `using` statement is indeed a good strategy to automatically close the stream in this case

Answer (score 2):

Here are some of the most important classes to do IO in C#:

**Raw binary IO**

- `Stream`: it's the base class for all classes that represent a sequential stream of bytes. The stream can be read-only, write-only or read-write. It provides methods like `Read`, `Write` and `Seek`. Keep in mind that a stream is used to access *raw, binary data*; depending on what you want to do, it might not be convenient to use it directly.

  - `FileStream`: a stream to read and/or write data in a file.
  - `MemoryStream`: a stream to read and write data in memory.

**Text IO**

- `TextReader`: it's the base class for all classes used to read a sequence of characters. It provides methods like `Read`, `ReadLine`, and `ReadToEnd`.

  - `StreamReader`: a `TextReader` that reads text from a `Stream`. A `StreamReader` always has an `Encoding` (UTF-8, ASCII, etc) that specifies how to convert the binary data from the stream into text.
  - `StringReader`: a `TextReader` that reads text from a `String` (useful to process an in-memory string as if it was the content of a file)
- `TextWriter`: it's the base class for all classes used to write a sequence of characters. It provides methods like `Write` and `WriteLine`.

  - `StreamWriter`: a `TextWriter` that writes text to a `Stream`. Like `StreamReader`, it has an `Encoding` that specifies how to convert the text to binary data.
  - `StringWriter`: a TextWriter that writes text to a `StringBuilder`.

The .NET framework also provides a helper class named `File` for simplified IO operations:

- the `ReadAllBytes` method returns all the content of a file as an array of bytes
- the `ReadAllText` method returns all the content of a file as a string
- the `ReadAllLines` method returns all the lines of text from a file as an array of strings
- the `WriteAllBytes` method writes the specified array of bytes to a file (replacing the existing content)
- the `WriteAllText` method writes the specified string to a file (replacing the existing content)
- the `WriteAllLines` method writes the specified lines of text to a file (replacing the existing content)

For more details, read the [documentation of the `System.IO` namespace on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

`C#` has nice built-in methods that allows you to easily read & manipulate file contents. For example if you want to read all the lines from a file you can simply use `File.ReadAllLines` method:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("your file path");
```

If you want to exclude some lines, you could use `File.ReadLines` method with `Linq`:

```
var filteredLines = File.ReadLines("your file path")
                    .Where(line => yourCondition)
                    .ToArray();
```

Those are just two simple example. See the documentation for more details:

1. [`File Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. [File and Stream I/O](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3352a4t(v=vs.110).aspx)